# AWS S3 using client side enctyption

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

I want to implement a client side encryption for data to be uploaded to an S3 bucket. However, since I have only basic knowledge in encryption I am a little confused with the examples I found to solve this problem.

For other programming languages like Java, .NET, Ruby, Go, ... the AWS SDK provides methods for client side encryption. And I also found examples [[1]](https://aioboto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cse.html)[[2]](https://github.com/tedder/s3-client-side-encryption/blob/master/get.py) that copy the same behavior for python.

However, all these examples end up using the AWS KMS service to generate, store and receive their encryption keys which I find confusing. From my understanding you have two general options:

- **You trust AWS or your data is not very sensitive:** Then you can use AWS server side encryption or no encryption at all.
- **Your data is sensitive and/or you don't want to trust AWS:** In this case I have to generate and manage the keys somewhere else than on AWS (correct?). Or is there any obstacle that prevents AWS to read your encrypted data if they wanted to?

Are there any obvious downsides in implementing a client side encryption by following a basic AES Tutorial [[3]](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html) and uploading the encrypted data?

Comment: You should look into envelope encryption: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html - in this, you need not trust AWS, since AWS only knows about the key used to encrypt your actual data.

Comment: I still don't see why I don't have to trust AWS using this CMK+Data Key enctyption method. E.g. reading these passages: - "CMKs are created in AWS KMS and never leave AWS KMS unencrypted. To use or manage your CMK, you access them through AWS KMS" - and - "Data keys are encryption keys [...]. You can use CMKs to generate, encrypt, and decrypt data keys. However, AWS KMS does not store, manage, or track your data keys, or perform cryptographic operations with data keys" Doesn't this mean that it is only the promise from AWS that prevents AWS from decryption my data?

Answer (score 3):

Key management (and rotation) is one downside. Now you have to manage the keys securely.

Failure of a client to actually encrypt data is another downside. With AWS-managed encryption you can set policies that deny non-encrypted uploads.

It's also possible that your encryption client may be bugged. It's not easy to write encryption software.